# C depth-first-search - how to handle not enough file pointers being available?

Tags: c, file, exit, depth-first-search, file-pointer

If I am recursively searching directories and entering all sub-directories, how can I handle not depth exceeding not enough file pointers being available and exit the program (without segmentation faults etc)?

Comment: You should only have a single directory open at a time for each level you're at.  So unless your directory tree is very deep it shouldn't be a problem.  Please show your code in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: `opendir` will fail when you run out of fds; as long as you're checking for that, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @zwol Would `ENOMEM` be the appropriate `errno` to look at?

Comment: I think @dbush is right -- a search of this type should not normally need to open huge numbers of file descriptors. I would guess that something is not being closed when it should. Need to see code, really.

Comment: Do you have an existing piece of code that is experiencing this problem? Or are you asking in a general sense?  If the former, post the code that has the problem.  If the latter, just make sure you close any file or directory descriptors when you're done using them.

Comment: @dbush I am not experiencing this problem but the professor says that if private test cases test this, the program must not break (exit gracefully).

Comment: @shurup EMFILE or ENFILE, actually, but _any_ `opendir` failure should be handled gracefully in this kind of code. You can easily run into EACCES for directories you aren't allowed to scan, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you have a queuing problem, so you should probably solve it with queues.  You have a protected resource -- number of fds you can have open at once; so you want to start with a q of one -- the root of the tree you are traversing.
As you traverse the tree, when you notice you have encountered a directory, put an item on the queue with that name.  Once you finish your directory, take an item from the queue and repeat the above sequence.

If you get clever, you can have multiple threads removing items from this queue, and processing the tree in parallel.   Of course you would have to arrange for the output to be ordered in some reasonable fashion.  Remember though, if you can only have N fds open, you can only have some M < N threads walking the directory.  With careful programming, you can effortlessly scale to this.